# Compare features of c# nlog viewers (on github)

Tags: logging, nlog

Can anyone compare or has anyone compared the features of the nlog viewers written in C# available on github?

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tools

It lists the following: Gibraltar, Sentinel, NLogViewer, LogEntries, Legit, ReflectInsight.

The following are features of interest. If you know any others please tell:

Compatibility: Log4J, Log4Net, NLog, ColdFusion, Customized

License.

App type. (Windows?)
Filtering
Highlights
Search
Bookmarks
Custom Configuration method (UI / XML / config file)
Complexity of configuration and UI

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak about ReflectInsight as I was once one of the developers for their product. One of their high end clients had a need to send 1.4 Billion log messages across a two day high burst time window to meet a very aggressive SLA. They dealt with high frequency phone switches that needed to be monitored and tracked using our watch feature.

The issues they found were as follows:

- Memory leaks (slow but concerning)
- Live Viewer freezing when high bursts occurred

These issues took a 2 weeks to address but it has been very successful. The Freezing was the easy bug, the memory leak was the worst but was nailed.

To this day, the Live Viewer in Auto Purge mode, is still running live without any shutdowns. The Live Viewer can now receive 100,000 msg/s. Which is very impressive.

Hope this helps. Yes I know, it's a paid product but you get what you paid for.

code